# What properties are available for `VBoxManage mediumproperty`?

Tags: virtualbox

I've tried a bunch of commands like `VBoxManage mediumproperty get my.vmdk size` and always get the same response:

```
VBoxManage: error: Property 'size' does not exist
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "GetProperty(Bstr(pszProperty).raw(), strVal.asOutParam())" at line 1774 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

There is no listing command and I could not see a list of properties in the documentation for [`mediumproperty`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-mediumproperty) or [`modifymedium`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi). `showmediuminfo` shows for example capacity, but that is not a property name.

Where can I find a list of property names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for a while too, then decided to use the API to check what properties were defined.

Here is the API docs for [`IMedium.getProperties`](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/interface_i_medium.html#abc89f219694ae6969dea62fb2319fbde). With this function, you can check what properties are defined.

It turns out only one property is available `AllocationBlockSize`.

The list of properties can also be obtained by [`IMediumFormat.describeProperties`](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/interface_i_medium_format.html#ad2efa4b9af144f87191d668475944e83) for the same result, one property named `AllocationBlockSize`.

A bit of an anti-climax, I was wishing to get the UUID from there!